# com.facebook.jni.CppException: getPropertyAsObject: property -- react native 0.64

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I am trying to update the react project, but i am having the next error

```
com.facebook.jni.CppException: getPropertyAsObject: property 'callFunctionReturnResultAndFlushedQueue' is not an Object

no stack
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

The json package is

```
{
"name": "test",
"version": "1.0.0",
"private": true,
"description": "test",
"scripts": {
},
"dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-native": "^0.64.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "5.6.1",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-fetch-polyfill": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-fs": "2.15.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.4",
    "react-native-permissions": "2.0.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-webview": "10.2.3",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^2.0.1"
}
```

}

I only change the next

Original

"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "^0.59.9",

Modified

"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-native": "^0.64.2",

When i generated the bundle with the last version, it is ok, but if i change the react and react native version , it is not ok